# Test S3 operations with simulated credentials

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-s3, boto3, moto

I'm writing unit tests for a function that should authenticate to AWS S3 and then perform some operations on S3. I have a bunch of functions that do various things (like downloading/uploading files, checking for existence, etc).

Since in production these will need authentication, I want to simulate it in the tests, so that I can check that this part of the code is ok too.

For mocking the AWS environment I'm using `moto`. As of now I have the following code, below. A quick intro to it: `my_head_bucket` is an example function that needs to have unit tests. `create_user_with_access_key_and_policy` should mock the IAM user and policy needed for authenticated S3 access. It is almost the same as in [the examples in the documentation](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_core/test_auth.py#L23).

Then there are two tests. The first should pass without errors (having the correct authentication). The second should fail with `ClientError`, because `"invalid"` keys are being passed.

For some reason I am not able to pass through the creation of the mock user and policy, getting `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AttachUserPolicy operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.` It seems that no authentication should be needed for `create_access_key`, so what am I doing wrong?

```
import os
import unittest
import boto3
import botocore
from moto import mock_s3, mock_iam
from botocore.client import ClientError
from moto.core import set_initial_no_auth_action_count

import json

def my_head_bucket(bucket, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key):
    """
    This is a sample function. In the real case, this function will do more than
    just heading a bucket (like uploading/downloading files or other actions).
    
    It would be imported from another module and should not have any decorators (like moto's)
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    s3_client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket)

@mock_iam
def create_user_with_access_key_and_policy(user_name="test-user"):
    """
    Should create a user with attached policy allowing read/write operations on S3.
    """
    policy_document = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {"Effect": "Allow", "Action": "s3:*", "Resource": "*"}
        ],
    }
    
    # Create client and user
    client = boto3.client("iam", region_name="us-east-1")
    client.create_user(UserName=user_name)

    # Create and attach the policy
    policy_arn = client.create_policy(
        PolicyName="policy1", PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy_document)
    )["Policy"]["Arn"]
    client.attach_user_policy(UserName=user_name, PolicyArn=policy_arn)
    
    # Return the access keys
    return client.create_access_key(UserName=user_name)["AccessKey"]

class TestMyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @set_initial_no_auth_action_count(0)
    @mock_s3
    def test_correct_credentials(self):
        """
        Sets the environment (creates user with keys and policy, creates the bucket), then calls
        the function-to-be-tested and expects it to run without exceptions.
        """
        ### Arrange
        iam_keys = create_user_with_access_key_and_policy()
        print(iam_keys)

        s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=iam_keys["AccessKeyId"],aws_secret_access_key=iam_keys["SecretAccessKey"])
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket='mock_bucket')
        
        my_head_bucket('mock_bucket', aws_access_key_id=iam_keys["AccessKeyId"],aws_secret_access_key=iam_keys["SecretAccessKey"])
        
    @set_initial_no_auth_action_count(0)
    @mock_s3
    def test_incorrect_credentials(self):
        """
        Sets the environment (creates user with keys and policy, creates the bucket), then calls
        the function-to-be-tested and expects it to run without exceptions.
        """
        ### Arrange
        iam_keys = create_user_with_access_key_and_policy()
        print(iam_keys)

        s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=iam_keys["AccessKeyId"],aws_secret_access_key=iam_keys["SecretAccessKey"])
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket='mock_bucket')
        
        with self.assertRaises(ClientError):
            my_head_bucket('mock_bucket', aws_access_key_id=iam_keys["AccessKeyId"],aws_secret_access_key="invalid")
```

Comment: To anyone interested, the answer is in this thread:

https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/4335